# i want to set the ng-show using ng-repeat array values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, ng-show

In my program I want to set `ng-show` values using variable so I change the `ng-show` whenever I want.

angular code is:

```
  var arrowup,arrowdown;
  arrdown=false;
  $scope.header=[{"name":"Subsection Header #1","arrowup":"arrowup","close":"close","arrowdown":"arrowdown","open":"open"}];

  $scope.open = function() {
        arrowdown = false;
        arrowup = true;
      }
```

Here I want to change the value of `ng-show` but it is not changing.

html code is:

```
  <div class="arrow-down" ng-repeat="header in header"   ng-click="this[header.open]()"    ng-show="header.arrowdown ">
```

Comment: `header in header` is ambiguos

Comment: `var arrowup,arrowdown;` ==> `$scope.arrowup` and `$scope.arrowdown`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use for binding to a template in Angular, use `$scope` instead.

Also you can't use `ng-repeat` with the same name.

Lastly, there's no need to put `this[header.open]()` in `ng-click` just use `open()`.

```
$scope.arrowdown=false;
$scope.header=[{"name":"Subsection Header #1","arrowup":"arrowup","close":"close","arrowdown":"arrowdown","open":"open"}];

$scope.open = function() {
    $scope.arrowdown = false;
    $scope.arrowup = true;
}

<div class="arrow-down" ng-repeat="head in header" ng-click="open()"    ng-show="head.arrowdown">
```

Comment: function is working problem ng-show is not changing .

Comment: Might want to change it to `ng-show="head.arrowdown"` to `ng-show="arrowdown"` depending on what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

this code would toggle show on click:

```
  $scope.headers=[{"name":"Subsection Header #1","arrowup":"arrowup","close":"close","arrowdown":"arrowdown","open":"open", show: false}];

  $scope.open = function(header) {
        header.show = !header.show;
      }

<div class="arrow-down" ng-repeat="header in headers"   ng-click="open(header)"    ng-show="header.show">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you really desire as output, I have created sample for you:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.arrowdown = true;
    $scope.arrowup = false;
  
    $scope.headers=[{
      "name":"Subsection Header#1",
      "arrowup":"arrowup",
      "close":"close",
      "arrowdown":"arrowdown",
      "open":"open"}];

  $scope.open = function() {
        $scope.arrowdown = !$scope.arrowdown;
        $scope.arrowup = !$scope.arrowup;
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div class="arrow-down" 
       ng-repeat="header in headers"    
       ng-show="arrowdown">{{header | json}}

  </div>
  <button ng-click="open()">Show/Hide</button>
</div>
```